# How to write custom hook for detecting hover of several elements?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Basically I want to write a hook to determine if hover was triggered over one of several buttons.

So far I have this:

```
enum buttons {
  oneButton: 'oneButton',
  anotherButton: 'anotherButton'
}

type UseHoverType= {
  [key in buttons]: boolean
}

export function useHover() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState<UseHoverType>({
    oneButton: false,
    anotherButton: false,
  })

  const handleHoverIn = useCallback((button: buttons) => () => {
    setIsHovered({
      [button]: true,
    })
  }, [])

  const handleHoverOut = useCallback((button: buttons) => () => {
    setIsHovered({
      [button]: false,
    })
  }, [])

  return {
    isHovered,
    handleHoverIn,
    handleHoverOut,
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting this Typescript error where `setIsHovered` is called:

```
The argument type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SetStateAction<UseHoverType>' 
"Type '{ [x: string]: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type 'UseHoverType': oneButton, anotherButton"
```

All the help with fixing this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
enum buttons {
  oneButton = 'oneButton',
  anotherButton = 'anotherButton'
}

type UseHoverType = Record<keyof typeof buttons, boolean>;
```

[image]

By the way, you can also use `enum buttons {oneButton, anotherButton}`, still the `UseHoverType` works.

**UPDATE 1:**
and use functional setState to set the new state, so your code will be like this:

```
enum buttons {
  oneButton,
  anotherButton
}

type buttonTypes = keyof typeof buttons;

type UseHoverType = Record<buttonTypes, boolean>;

export function useHover() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState<UseHoverType>({
    oneButton: false,
    anotherButton: false
  });

  const handleHoverIn = useCallback(
    (button: buttonTypes) => () => {
      setIsHovered(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [button]: true }));
    },
    []
  );

  const handleHoverOut = useCallback(
    (button: buttonTypes) => () => {
      setIsHovered(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [button]: true }));
    },
    []
  );

  return {
    isHovered,
    handleHoverIn,
    handleHoverOut
  };
}
```

Comment: No, getting the same error

Comment: what about this one? @Person